# I want to use OneHotEncoder in Single Categorical column

Tags: python, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

Here shape of df is (190,2) where 1st column is x and is a categorical value and @nd column is Integer.

```
X = df.iloc[:,0].values
y = df.iloc[:,-1].values

# Encoding categorical data

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
X = labelencoder.fit_transform(X)
X.reshape(-1,1)
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Here I wanted to change the Categorical value X using OneHotEncoder to predict y. But When I run this code, I am getting an error.

`ValueError: bad input shape ()`

Can someone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) does not require for the input features to be numerical. So you can just feed it directly the categorical features:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
X_oh = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

In the case of having a `1D` array, as is usually the case of `y`, you'll need to reshape the array into a `2D` one:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
X_oh = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
```

---

Do note however that the following:

```
X.reshape(-1,1)
```

Is not doing anything. It is not performing an in-place operation. You have to assign it back to a variable.